# AWS trying to use Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Sorry for doing this kind of question.. but I´m a bit lost here....

I have an app which consist in an Angular4 as frontend and Java app as Backend.
But I´m planning to use AWS Lambda as I´m interested after seeing the videos in Amazon.

The issue is that I don´t know how to get the best from AWS.

My Java app has a very time consuming task to process some images (which takes several seconds).

But I'm not sure if I can deploy all my app in Lambda, or if the idea is to use a EC2 server and then the specific task for the image processing in the lambda. Can anyone please shed some light here?

Also, the frontend app can be deploy in a lambda, or again, lambda is just for specific task?

EDIT:
The application flow would be:
The user in the angular app upload an image, the image goes to the backend server in Java and it´s stored in (maybe) a AWS bucket.. Then the Java app with imagemagick process the image and the result is store in (maybe) another bucket.

So the question is when I need to use Lambda? just to convert the image or if the full backend (and maybe frontend) app would be there?<

I'm asking because I cannot find enough information about that...

Comment: Can you describe the flow you are planning for image processing with Lambda? Is it triggered from Angular App?

Comment: Hi! @Ashan I've just added the flow. thanks!

Comment: The question of when to use lambda is really up to you. A framework like [serverless](https://serverless.com) would let you do everything using lambda so thats definitely an option. You'll need to refactor your app a bit to get that working.

Comment: Lambda has no problem with "several seconds" the timeout  can be adjusted to hundreds of seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can deploy your Angular frontend to Amazon S3. Also you can use AWS CloudFront to add custom domains and free SSL certificates from Amazon using Amazon Certificate Manager for your domain. For more details refer the article [Deploying Angular/React Apps in AWS](https://codeburst.io/deploying-angular-react-apps-in-aws-ec55a4fb7446).

**If you don't need to show tge image processing results immediately in frontend**

For the image processing backend you can use AWS API Gateway and Lambda along with S3. For this recommended flow is you can use the API Backend to get an Signed URL or AWS STS in Lambda (Or Use Cognito Federated Identities) to get temporary access to Amazon S3 Bucket to Upload the image directly to S3 from Angular App. For more details on this refer  the article [Upload files Securely to AWS S3 Directly from Browser](https://medium.com/@ashan.fernando/upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-signed-urls-fa0a0cf489db).

Note: AWS recently released a JavaScript Library called [AWS Amplify](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify) to simplify the implementation of the above tasks.

After Uploading the image to S3 you can setup an event driven workflow by using Amazon S3 triggers to invoke an Lambda function to perform the image processing and save the process image back to S3 (If you need to store the result).

**If you need to show the result immediately**

Still use tge previous approach upto Upload to S3 from frontend and then invoke an API Gateway Lambda function passing the file path in S3 to process the image.

To understand the details in connecting both frontend and backend with AWS serverless technologies refer the article [Full Stack Serverless Web Apps with AWS](https://medium.com/99xtechnology/full-stack-serverless-web-apps-with-aws-189d87da024a).

As a side note, you should be able to implement the required functionality with AWS Lambda without using AWS EC2.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! Could you please tell me which one you suggest? If full Lambda or a mix with Lambda and EC2?

Comment: How frequent the image processing take place? And how much time takes on average?